# Scipy solver returns an error/How to use numpy.seterr?

Tags: numpy, scipy, solver

How do I figure out what causes this error?

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars and dx_norm/self.x_rtol <= x_norm))
```

There isn't really anything important in my code, it's just scipy solver function, specifically newton_krylov. I found that I have to use numpy.seterr to trace the error, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was going on, but I set `x_rtol=1e-12` and it stopped throwing this error